# problem with c++ forward class declaration

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract, forward-declaration

Im' having problem with pure virtual methods and forward class declaration.
The following program compiles, but will not link.

```
class SubClass;

class SuperClass {
    public:
    virtual SubClass& GetSomething() = 0;
};

class SubClass: public SuperClass {
    public:
    SubClass& GetSomething();
};


SubClass& SubClass::GetSomething()
{
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    SuperClass *obj = new SubClass();
    SubClass result = obj->GetSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for SuperClass in classtest-56e822.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for SubClass in classtest-56e822.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in classtest-56e822.o
  "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
      vtable for SuperClass in classtest-56e822.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious to cause that error, but you should make sure to mark the function in the derived class with `override`, so you can be sure there isn't a misspelling or something causing it.

Comment: How do you want to correctly `delete obj;`? Virtual classes always should provide a virtual detructor! Side note: you did not delete, so actually, you got a memory leak (only being cleaned up by OS - *if* you are on one that does - when your application exits).

Comment: Which compiler and switches are you using? Using G++ on LInux I cannot reproduce the error. BTW: The virtual destructor is missing...

Comment: I tried to compile&run your code, but could not produce an error on my side. I am using MinGW on Windows.

Comment: The error message comes from gcc on my Mac.  Having the same problem within xcode (which also uses gcc).

Comment: Xcode uses clang, not gcc. And it would tell you that the virtual destructor (that sometimes triggers the vtable being added) is missing. Add it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31861803/608639) and [c++ a missing vtable error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265106/608639)

Comment: To be precise: Apple replaced gcc as default compiler with clang - and left a symlink from gcc to clang for compatibility. But you *could* explicitly install gcc on your system and replace the symlink to enforce GCC, if you wanted to.

Comment: @jww: Really a duplicate? Other question did declare destructor, but not define it - this one does not declare at all, thus a (but non-virtual) default is generated... I'd say it is a seemingly marginal, but essential difference.

Comment: @Aconcagua There are no duplicate indeed. And I cannot reproduce this error message on my system neither with clang nor with gcc. Certainly a bug of your compiler.

Comment: There can only be one kind of `SubClass` for your `SuperClass` and you can't instantiate the `SuperClass `.  What is the point then, of having two separate classes ?

Comment: My compiler does not run into this issue.  But, as a workaround, you can do this in a CPP file `SubClass& SuperClass::GetSomething() { throw Blah(); };` to generate the vtable in that translation unit.  Even though it was declared pure virtual, you can still define an implementation for it.